# changing the sylesheet of a .js file

Tags: javascript

I got a .js file for menu stylesheet which I have to change.This file contains

```
stm_bm(["menu4b6c",730,"","images/",0,"","",0,0,250,0,1000,1,0,0,"","",0,0,1,2,"default","hand",""],this);
stm_bp("p0",[0,4,0,0,0,0,0,16,100,"",-2,"",-2,50,0,0,"#999999","transparent","",3,0,0,"#4D2912"]);
stm_ai("p0i0",[6,1,"transparent","images/sep.png",2,25,0]);
stm_ai("p0i1",[0,"About Us","","",-1,-1,0,"#","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"images/yellow5-d.gif","images/yellow5-d.gif",16,6,0,1,1,"#FFFFF7",1,"#D8D8D8",0,"","",3,0,0,0,"#FFFFF7","#000000","#FFFFFF","#000000","bold 14px Verdana","bold 14px Verdana",0,0],111,35);
stm_bpx("p1","p0",[1,4,0,2,2,5,0,0,98,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Inset(,enabled=0,Duration=0.30)",-2,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Pixelate(MaxSquare=15,enabled=0,Duration=0.30)",-2,80,2,3,"#999999","#eefcd2","",3,1,1]);
stm_aix("p1i0","p0i1",[0,"Vision","","",-1,-1,0,"vision.html","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#dcf2b1",0,"#ecfccd",0,"","",3,3,0,0,"#FFFFF7","#000000","#000000","#000000","12px 'Arial','Verdana'","12px 'Arial','Verdana'"]);
```

Now I want to change the a:hover background of this menu.So I made edit to the line

```
stm_ai("p0i1",[0,"About Us","","",-1,-1,0,"#","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"images/yellow5-d.gif","images/yellow5-d.gif",16,6,0,1,1,"#FFFFF7",1,"#D8D8D8",0,"","",3,0,0,0,"#FFFFF7","#000000","#FFFFFF","#000000","bold 14px Verdana","bold 14px Verdana",0,0],111,35);
```

where #D8D8D8 was my hover background color.Now I want to give a background image in that part so what should I do.I made edit in many parts but failed.So pls help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe one of the "images/yellow5-d.gif"? Anyway post code for the function `stm_ai` and we'll be able to give real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Facetiously I would suggest changing to something that uses CSS for styles, not semi-obfuscated Javascript! That's the best answer I can give.

Comment: More fit to be comment, not answer.

Comment: I genuinely believe that is the answer!

Comment: No, this might be good comment but it does not answer the question itself in any way. As comment, I would upvote it but as answer I have to downvote it sorry.

Comment: It might not be a direct answer to fix the issue, @jayp has touched on the fact that the original code is not easily maintained or self-documenting.  There are a bunch of plugins and scripts that will take simple markup or arrays and generate menus for you that would be much easier to maintain - thus I too would recommend to find an alternative solution.